# One more... parent variables in nested foreach-object

Tags: powershell

why is it not working?

```
1..2 | % {
    3..4 | % {
        Get-Variable -Name '_' -Scope 0
        Get-Variable -Name '_' -Scope 1 # <===
    }
    Get-Variable -Name '_' -Scope 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working as you expect because `%` (`ForEach-Object`) does not introduce a new scope.

Here is the proof: `$x` is changed in the same scope, in the parent it would be not changed:

```
$x = 'old'
1 | % { $x = 'new' }
$x
```

If you need scopes then you may use the construct `&{process{...}}` instead of `ForEach-Object`

```
1..2 | & {process{
    3..4 | & {process{
        Get-Variable -Name '_' -Scope 0
        Get-Variable -Name '_' -Scope 1 # <===
    }}
    Get-Variable -Name '_' -Scope 0
}}
```

The above works as expected.

Note: `&{process{...}}` (new scope) or `.{process{...}}` (same scope) are also faster than `%`.